# Remove all name from desktop icon in windows 11 desktop

Tags: windows-11

Hello how I can remove the name from icon in desktop like This Pc to nothing that actually show me the icon of this pc?

Answer (score 1):

I think Windows doesn't have options to do that.

For me, there is a trick to do that but you have to repeat with each files and folders:

You can try naming files and folders that you want to hide the name with "Hidden character". To type that "Hidden Character", please using `Alt + 255` or `Alt + 0160`.

*Note that: Files and Folders cannot have the same name, eg.: If File1 is named with one "Hidden Character", File2 must name with two "Hidden Characters"*

Btw, I think there are some third-party programs that can hide it from the icons. This must be the easier way

Comment: For trash and this pc works but for ink files not worked(error same file name)

Comment: I added two or three more character and hidded the name!